# Own Android hardware keyboard shortcuts

Tags: android, keyboard, hardware, shortcut, chars

I want to make **own** shortcuts to use with **hardware** keyboard on **android** phones like *Milestone/Droid, T-Mobile G1/HTC Dream and T-Mobile G2/Desire Z*.
It will be cool to have alt+e shortcut to make ę for example, without changing keyboard. (It's my national chars)

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I have a similar problem.  I want to run an application like gallery when I hit **F2** on my external keyboard.

What I have deduced so far is that we need to somehow override the `PhoneWindowManager.java` class function `interceptKeyBeforeQueueing` to detect a particular keystroke and add our own behavior to it.

Another place you can catch the key event is `InputDispatcher.java`.

I still need to verify the concept itself. If you have any solution please share.